# How to generate a suffix of increasing number for the repeated values in a colum?

Tags: r

So I have this column consisting of species names:

```
species
Dasyatis pastinaca
Amblyraja radiata
Raja montagui
Raja montagui
Dasyatis pastinaca
Himantura imbricata
Mobula thurstoni
Raja montagui
Mobula thurstoni
Dalatias licha
```

As you can see many of them are repeated and what I'm trying to do is, for every set of repeated names, add a suffix which is their id number. Basically this is the output I'm looking for:

```
Dasyatis pastinaca_01
Amblyraja radiata_01
Raja montagui_01
Raja montagui_02
Dasyatis pastinaca_02
Himantura imbricata_01
Mobula thurstoni_01
Raja montagui_03
Mobula thurstoni_02
Dalatias licha_01
```

I've tried some things that have failed 100%

Comment: Use `paste0(df$column,"_",1:length(unique(df)))`

Comment: it didn't work sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you the expected output:

```r
library(tidyverse)

dataframe <- tibble(
  species = c(
    'Dasyatis pastinaca',
    'Amblyraja radiata',
    'Raja montagui',
    'Raja montagui',
    'Dasyatis pastinaca',
    'Himantura imbricata',
    'Mobula thurstoni',
    'Raja montagui',
    'Mobula thurstoni',
    'Dalatias licha'
  )
)
```

You can do it like that:

```r
dataframe %>%
  group_by(species) %>%
  mutate(species2 = str_c(species, '_', str_pad(row_number(), 2, pad = '0')))
#> # A tibble: 10 x 2
#> # Groups:   species [6]
#>    species             species2              
#>    <chr>               <chr>                 
#>  1 Dasyatis pastinaca  Dasyatis pastinaca_01 
#>  2 Amblyraja radiata   Amblyraja radiata_01  
#>  3 Raja montagui       Raja montagui_01      
#>  4 Raja montagui       Raja montagui_02      
#>  5 Dasyatis pastinaca  Dasyatis pastinaca_02 
#>  6 Himantura imbricata Himantura imbricata_01
#>  7 Mobula thurstoni    Mobula thurstoni_01   
#>  8 Raja montagui       Raja montagui_03      
#>  9 Mobula thurstoni    Mobula thurstoni_02   
#> 10 Dalatias licha      Dalatias licha_01
```

Because `species` column is a grouping one you can't modify it. You may later change the name of a new column to the old one:

```r
dataframe %>%
  group_by(species) %>%
  mutate(species2 = str_c(species, '_', str_pad(row_number(), 2, pad = '0'))) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-species) %>% 
  rename(species = species2)
#> # A tibble: 10 x 1
#>    species               
#>    <chr>                 
#>  1 Dasyatis pastinaca_01 
#>  2 Amblyraja radiata_01  
#>  3 Raja montagui_01      
#>  4 Raja montagui_02      
#>  5 Dasyatis pastinaca_02 
#>  6 Himantura imbricata_01
#>  7 Mobula thurstoni_01   
#>  8 Raja montagui_03      
#>  9 Mobula thurstoni_02   
#> 10 Dalatias licha_01
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>